# Custom CSS completions not working for values

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I was trying to create my own `.sublime-completions` for CSS files and ran into the following problem. The completions only work for properties, but not for their values.

See the following two examples, with the pipe-symbol `|` representing the cursor position.

i. Working:

```
body {
| 
}
```

ii. Not working:

```
body {
    color: |
}
```

My `.sublime-completions` looks like this:

```
{
        "scope": "source.css, source.sass, source.scss",

        "completions":
        [
            { "trigger": "foo", "contents": "bar" }
        ]
}
```

Apart from Sublime Text 3's default CSS package, I don't use any other packages working in the CSS scope.

Comment: can you add the actual contents of the `.sublime-completions` file that are working and not working, and indicate which is which? Also, please describe in your question what the "not working" is actually supposed to look like if it was working.

Comment: Okay, you can actually try and use the example file, for it has the same problem as my actual completions. The completion-popup only shows up in my first example, but never in the second. Forcing the completion-popup to display doesn't work either.

Comment: I was looking for some existing CSS completions, but they all either complete the properties only (not their values) or are implemented in Python. Wondering why that is.